# IIS process recycle and session variables

Tags: iis-6

Is it a bad idea to setup a web application on client PCs with Windows XP (there are ten workstations), rather than on a server (Windows Server 2003).

I have an ASP.NET application, which has a memory leak and uses session variables.  I believe that the session variables may be causing problems when the IIS process recycles.  Is there any benefit of installing IIS on a server rather than on workstations?

I was debating to myself whether to ask this question here or on server vault.  As my question references session variables I decided to ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is regarding session variables or a memory leak it really doesn't matter where you run it because the problem is in code, not in the platform.

The only possible benefit to running a problematic application like this on Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6) rather than on Windows XP (IIS 5.1) is that you can schedule recycles for the Application pools under IIS 6 and may be able to put a band-aid over the problem by recycling often and changing the code to store session out-of-process.

Bottom line - fix the code and run the application where it makes sense to run it.